# new git breaks windows git shell

Tags: git, github-desktop

Platform: Windows 7,
Git Shell running ConEmu

When I fired up Git Shell today a window popped offering to install the latest version of Git. In the past this process has worked without incident. Today, following the upgrade, Git shell does not detect git. For example, if I type

```
git status
```

I get

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Consulting the Windows PATH, it looks like several new entries have been tacked onto the front

```
PATH=C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd;
C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin;
C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\share\git-tfs;
C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\XPC72D0A.GQE\ZBYYH2JR.XW2\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0003_5794af8169eeff14;
C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\GitHub\lfs-amd64_1.5.5;
```

Presumably all this new material in the PATH should allow git to be detected; otherwise, what's it doing there? In fact, I would think a single PATH entry should be sufficient to allow git to be found.

So, is there a horrible bug in the installation process of the latest git for Windows? Or is there some tweak I need to perform to make this all right?

Comment: Which means that your GIT is relocated or deleted. Perform `git init` or `git -v` to see if it is actually deleted. If it works which means that ur repository .git folder got deleted.

Comment: The .git folder is in place. The point is, the git ***program*** is not detected, despite multiple PATH entries that are there, presumably, to tell Windows where it is.

Comment: You seem to be using Github desktop. Is the "Git shell" some startup link provided by it? Git for Windows defines "Git bash" and "Git CMD", and none of them I have seen suggesting any update

Comment: Yes, I'm using GitHub Desktop and it installs a 'Git Shell' on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling [GitHub Desktop, and re-installing it completely](https://desktop.github.com/).

Also, as a workaround, don't forget that you can uncompress the self-extracting archive [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), and add that folder to `%PATH%`.

Comment: I followed your advice and uninstalled/reinstalled GitHub Desktop. This seems to have put things right.